# React Component properties "state" and "setState" are not recognized in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio

I'm trying to reproduce this:[ASP.NET Core: CRUD With React.js and Entity Framework Core](https://dzone.com/articles/aspnet-core-crud-with-reactjs-and-entity-framework), on Visual Studio 2019 with IIS Express (with no Node.js). The typescript files are compiled with NuGet Microsoft.Typescript.MsBuild (3.3.3).
But the compilation does not run for Typescript files, since properties "state" and "setState" are not recognized (Visual Studio message is "does not exist") although the TypeScript class inheriting from React.Component.

I have tried changing the javascript compilation to Ecma 6/5/2016...

```js
    import React from 'react';

    export class GetUser extends React.Component  {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = ...
```

this.state is underlined with red in Visual Studio, and therefore the file is not transpiled

Comment: I never managed to get `import React from 'react'` to actually work in my TS files. It always requires me to use `import * as React from 'react'`

Comment: Component is recognized, so it is not the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `react` is not exposing it's types. It means that typescript does not know which attributes or methods are declared in `React.Component`.

And because it doesn't know that `this.state` exists, it shows you an error.

In order to makes the linter knowing `React.Component` type, install the package [@types/react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react), like :

```
npm install --save @types/react
```

---

Also, I don't do react, but I've found this :

> Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may
>   replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were
>   immutable.

[Documentation](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state)

Comment: Since it's in the constructor is a valid place to set the initial state, but other than that yes, you don't mutate state directly, only via setState().

Answer (score 0):

```
**Please try below code it'll help you to find your error.**


import React from 'react';

        class GetUser extends React.Component  {
            constructor(props){
                super(props);
                this.state = {
                name:'Demo';
            }
        }
        render(){
            return(
                <div>{this.state.demo}</div>
            )
        }
         }

        export default GetUser;
```

Comment: Prakash, you should understand that I cannot compile this code. That's the problem